# svn diff for binary file(excel file)

Tags: svn, binaryfiles

I have configured  svn repository for an excel file,

So I checked out and create myworkingdirectory
Then I changed the excel file and I wanted to see the changes by **svn diff**

which  It says that file marked binary eventhough I have changed

**Subversion client configuration file and**

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes
```

and also I have added this line

```
*.xlsx = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

When I use

```
svn proplist --verbose /path to /myworkingdirectory/file.xlsx
```

it lists the **mime-type** and its value

I dont know what else to do to see the changes by svn diff like its  possible to see in text format files

Comment: Hello! I think this question is applicable for your question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659740/how-well-does-svn-work-for-office-2007-documents

Comment: @ProtosZetZ Thanks for the comment, I am really confused if its doable at all ? I have seen most of these questions before posting my question but I could not conclude any consensus

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins for TortoiseSVN that let you diff Office documents:

http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiff/e/index.html

Comment: quite outdated, as far as I see

Answer (score 0):

Xlsx are nothing more than zip containing several XML files.
SVN will not be able to diff them as text files since they are binary.

Comment: So there is noway I can see the changes that I made?

Comment: No, you can't. You can store them revision per revision, but the diff will only show binary chars. A cumbersome solution can be unzip those xlsx files and commit them as folders. Then, after downloading an update, zip to xlsx. After editing in excel, before commit, unzip them again. But, as said before, is not a convenient solution, although theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Windows & Office Professional Plus 2013 or Office 365 ProPlus I recomend to use Spreadsheet Compare as this analyses also the xls built in history.

Call this small xlsdiff.bat from SNV:

```
set path2=%1
set mine=%2
set mine=%mine:"=%
ECHO %mine% > tmp.txt
dir %path2% /B /S >> tmp.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE" tmp.txt
```

Configure svn to call "xlsdiff.bat %base %mine"