# SVN Diff: Why are some files marked as binary

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, mime-types, file-type

Directly related:  [svn diff: file marked as binary type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634043/svn-diff-file-marked-as-binary-type) *(Per the comment on the answer)*

Why would my SVN client mark some files as binary?

Specifically, `.sql` has prop `svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream` when using TortoiseSVN.

I checked Right-click > Tortoise context menu > Settings > General > Subversion configuration file, and nothing is *uncommented* in `[miscellany]` or `[auto-props]`, so where is the decision coming from?

From what I can see in the related posts, I can "fix it" by either deleting the property on affected files, or globally change the behavior on new files via config/setting, but is there a "simple" way to do both for all affected files?

Somewhat related:

- [Persistently overriding svn's mime to binary mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580092/persistently-overriding-svns-mime-to-binary-mapping?lq=1)
- [svn diff for binary file(excel file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159340/svn-diff-for-binary-fileexcel-file?rq=1)

Comment: Jeez, and removing the `mime-type` property (assuming it's defaulting to `text/plain`) shows a bunch of `NUL` character garbage every other character.  Is my scenario just not applicable?  The TortoiseMerge viewer compares it fine...

Comment: I've got the same exact problem ... `.sql` files keep getting uploaded as `application/octet-stream` when they're clearly `text/plain`, with no `auto-props` set. Too bad no one has supplied an answer :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, I found the issue in my particular case:

A developer had saved a template `.sql` file he was using for new scripts. This file, somehow, was saved with `UCS-2` (or `Unicode`) encoding. Whenever he added files, TortoiseSVN determined that it was a binary file. By switching the encoding to `UTF-8`, the template and files derived from it are added correctly as `text/plain`.

**Additional Info** (Edit)

I found what might have been the culprit. When generating some scripts using the GUI, SQL Server Management Studio writes them as `Unicode` in the query window. If the file is saved, it will be saved as `Unicode` as well. Interestingly enough, files opened via the `File`>`New` don't save like this. An issue was raised with Microsoft about this back in 2007 (found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288677/unicode-defaults-on-ssms-save)), that apparently hasn't been resolved.

Comment: well that's going to be a pain to track down...but worth a shot

Comment: I was able to spot it because of `Notepad++`, which has a nice `Encoding...` menu that allows you to view current and change encoding.

Comment: Yeah, Notepad++ makes it easy to fix per file, but if you've got many files it seems a [batch script](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158633-how-to-check-text-file-encoding-from-command-line/) (or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684793/powershell-batch-change-files-encoding-to-utf-8)) will be necessary.

Comment: Agreed. I've added more information for the sake of completeness (e.g. how the files might have gotten into UCS-2 in the first place)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick way to fix this problem:

```
notepad %APPDATA%\Subversion\config
```

Scroll down to and uncomment this line:

```
enable-auto-props = yes
```

Under [auto-props] add this line:

```
*.sql = svn:mime-type=text/plain
```

Now when you add .SQL files to SVN, they will automatically be marked as text (not octet-stream).

EDIT: Removed unnecessary line ending file alteration.

Comment: Interesting.  I had done the same thing, only difference was that my auto-props were set to `*.sql = svn:mime-type=application/x-sql` instead (not sure why).  Changing it to your suggestion made it show up as I wanted when committing.
But I would point out that the `svn:eol-style=native` isn't necessary, and it's actually changing the file on disk.

Comment: I'd mark this the answer but it doesn't seem to help for existing files.

Comment: Existing files will have to be checked out, have their properties altered, and checked in again. But that is really a different question.

Comment: the correct and IANA-registered mime type for SQL is `application/sql` per [RFC 6922](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6922). Not sure what this does to TortoiseSVN's behavior.

Comment: The only way I was able to get JSON and SQL to display on an `svn diff` was to use `text/plain` as my mime type. Their respective application mime-types produce the following message for me when I try to see a difference: `Cannot display: file marked as a binary type`